# node asynchronous with response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

```
function getResultsForOneDev(devID, res) {

    var Contribution = require('../db/Contribution.js').model;
    var SurveyState = require('../db/SurveyState.js').model;
    var SurveyAnswer = require('../db/SurveyAnswer.js').model;

    var contributionList = {
        "dev": [ {
            "contribs" : [ {
                "surveyStates" : [ {
                    "surveyAnswers" : [ { } ]
                } ]
            } ]
        } ]
    };

    Contribution.find({dev:devID}).exec(function (error, contribs){
        // console.log("contribs:"+contribs);        

        contributionList = contribs;
        console.log("contribs length:"+contribs.length);

        for (var i = 0 ; i<contribs.length ; i++) {

            (function(oneContrib) {

                //console.log('contribs ID '+oneContrib._id);

                SurveyState.find({contrib:oneContrib._id}).exec(function (error, surveyStates){

                    // console.log("surveyStates:"+surveyStates);

                    oneContrib.surveyStates = surveyStates;
                    console.log("surveyStates length:"+surveyStates.length);

                    for (var j = 0 ; j<surveyStates.length ; j++) {

                        (function(oneSurveyState) {

                            SurveyAnswer.find({surveyState:oneSurveyState._id}).exec(function (error, surveyAnswers){

                                // console.log("surveyAnswers:"+surveyAnswers);

                                oneSurveyState.surveyAnswers = surveyAnswers;
                                console.log("surveyAnswers length:"+surveyAnswers.length);

                            });
                        })(surveyStates[j]);
                    }
                });
            })(contribs[i]);
        };

    });
    res.jsonp(contributionList);
}
```

This program does not run as I want, res.jsonp return empty contributionList.
I already try with async (https://github.com/caolan/async). What is the good pratice to fill contributionList before sending a res.jsonp ?

Comment: The easiest way to solve this would be using async.  Can you post the version of the code that uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your database queries are asynchronous (they finish sometime later) and the rest of your code does not wait for them, your two `for` loops will finish long before the actual async responses will.  As such, you have to actually keep track (somehow) of when the last async response is done and thus all the data in now in the `contributionList` data structure so you can now send your response.

My preference would be to use promises for this and `Promise.all()` to trigger an action when an arbitrary number of asynchronous operations are complete, but I don't know the database interfaces you're using to know which ones are promisified, so here's a generic method that simply uses a manual counter to keep track of how many async operations are still in flight and when the counter gets to zero, you have all the data now and you can send the response.

The additions to this code are the lines of code that use the variable `remaining`.

```
function getResultsForOneDev(devID, res) {

    var Contribution = require('../db/Contribution.js').model;
    var SurveyState = require('../db/SurveyState.js').model;
    var SurveyAnswer = require('../db/SurveyAnswer.js').model;

    var contributionList = {
        "dev": [ {
            "contribs" : [ {
                "surveyStates" : [ {
                    "surveyAnswers" : [ { } ]
                } ]
            } ]
        } ]
    };

    Contribution.find({dev:devID}).exec(function (error, contribs){
        // console.log("contribs:"+contribs);        

        contributionList = contribs;
        console.log("contribs length:"+contribs.length);

        // keep track of how many async responses are left to be processed
        // in a variable at a higher scope
        var remaining = 0;

        for (var i = 0 ; i<contribs.length ; i++) {

            (function(oneContrib) {

                //console.log('contribs ID '+oneContrib._id);

                SurveyState.find({contrib:oneContrib._id}).exec(function (error, surveyStates){

                    // console.log("surveyStates:"+surveyStates);

                    oneContrib.surveyStates = surveyStates;
                    console.log("surveyStates length:"+surveyStates.length);

                    // add how many more responses are pending
                    remaining += surveyStates.length;

                    for (var j = 0 ; j<surveyStates.length ; j++) {

                        (function(oneSurveyState) {

                            SurveyAnswer.find({surveyState:oneSurveyState._id}).exec(function (error, surveyAnswers){

                                // console.log("surveyAnswers:"+surveyAnswers);

                                oneSurveyState.surveyAnswers = surveyAnswers;
                                console.log("surveyAnswers length:"+surveyAnswers.length);

                                // mark one more processed and see if all remaining ones are done
                                --remaining;
                                if (remaining === 0) {
                                    res.jsonp(contributionList);
                                }

                            });
                        })(surveyStates[j]);
                    }
                });
            })(contribs[i]);
        };

    });
}
```

P.S. You should realize that you are somewhat flooding your database with a whole bunch of requests all at once (all attempting to run in parallel) and then sometime later the database will actually finish all of them.  Depending upon the structure of the database and its ability to handle this flood of requests efficiently or share load with other users also using the database, this is sometimes not a best practice.  So, sometimes it is better to send some small number of requests at once (e.g. 3-5) and each time one completes, you launch the next waiting request.  The async library can do that type of management for you or you can fairly simply build your own little queue of requests and each time one finishes, you send another.

Comment: Hello, thank you for yours replies. I finally take this purpose : using the remaining and it runs. I forget to delete res.end() in an other function, after calling the getResultsForOneDev function.

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` is asynchronous. It returns immediately, before the callback has populated values into `contributionList`.

Move your `res.jsonp()` to the end of the callback code where `contributionList` is populated rather than outside the callback.

Since you seem to have multiple `find()` inside loops and whatnot, and you cannot guarantee the order the callbacks will run, you can use `async` (as you mention) to create a workflow to insure they all finish, and then run a final callback (executed by `async`) to invoke `res.jsonp()`.